# Python not finding file in the same directory

Tags: python

I am writing a simple script that attaches file to a mail, but it is not finding the file. This is my one block:

```
    # KML attachment
    filename='20140210204804.kml'
    fp = open(filename, "rb")
    att = email.mime.application.MIMEApplication(fp.read(),_subtype="kml")
    fp.close()
    att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=filename)
    msg.attach(att)
```

The file 20140210204804.kml is present in the same folder as the script. I am getting below error:

```
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '20140210204804.kml'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you running the script? The current directory isn't necessarily the same as the script's location.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The working directory is not set to the directory of the script, but to the current directory where you started the script.

Use `__file__` to determine the file location and use that as a starting point to make `filename` an absolute path:

```
import os

here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

filename = os.path.join(here, '20140210204804.kml')
```

Comment: Excellent !! I didn't think this way. I can understand what "**__file__**" did, but is there any link that can explain why/how it did?

Comment: @Abhishekdotpy: most of the 'trick' here is using the [`os.path` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html); look for `abspath` and `dirname` there. `__file__` is just the filename of the current module, which *can* be relative to the working directory.

Comment: @Abhishekdotpy: `__file__` is documented both in the [`import` statement documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=__file__#the-import-statement) and the [Python datamodel document](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html).