# I am getting a no such file or directory when I have the file on my computer

Tags: python

This is the error code I am getting when I am trying to run my program.

```
 ChargAcc = open('charge_accounts.txt', 'r')
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'charge_accounts.txt'
```

Should I just redownload the file and see if it will work?

```
ChargAcc = open('charge_accounts.txt', 'r')


userValue=input('Enter Charge Account Number: ')


lines = ChargAcc.readlines()

for i in range(len(lines)):
     lines[i] = lines[i].rstrip('\n')

if userValue not in lines:
    print('Invalid')
else:
    print('Valid')

#close text
ChargAcc.close()
```

Comment: Note that the program tries to find `charge_accounts.txt` relative to the *directory your user is in when starting the program*, not relative to the *directory containing the program*. Thus, you need to not just assert that the file exists for this to be an actionable question, but speak to *where* the file exists, and what the user's *current working directory* is at the time.

Comment: If that is in fact the problem, then this is a duplicate of [python not finding file in the same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957131/python-not-finding-file-in-the-same-directory). If it's *not*, please [edit] the question to contain enough details to demonstrate the difference.

Comment: use path file for open file. like : `ChargAcc = open('c:/users/desktop/charge_accounts.txt', 'r')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was previously answered in [Python not finding file in the same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957131/python-not-finding-file-in-the-same-directory).

You can use those lines of code instead

```py
import os

path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'charge_accounts.txt')
ChargAcc = open(path, 'r')
```

Comment: Insofar as this answer is already covered in [Python not finding file in the same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957131/python-not-finding-file-in-the-same-directory), it would seem more appropriate to vote-to-close, rather than to add a duplicative answer -- no? See the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the bullet point regarding questions that "have already been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: I didn't know about the mentioned question. I wanted to help someone in a problem that I have faced recently. I'll edit my answer to include the previously answered question.

Answer (score 0):

I reverted back to the older try of the program and added in the new parts I wrote and was able to get it to work. This is my program that I made to get it to work.

```
Read_Account = open('charge_accounts.txt', "r")

accNumber = input("Please enter the seven numbers to a charge account:")

lines = Read_Account.readlines()

for i in range(len(lines)):
         lines[i] = lines[i].rstrip('\n')


if accNumber not in lines:
    print('was found in the list.')
else:
        print('was not found in the list.')




Read_Account.close()
```

Comment: None of the changes here have anything to do with the `open()` line at all. Something you do *after the `open()` call finishes* can't possibly change whether the `open()` succeeds. As such, I strongly suspect that while in the process of reverting to your old code, you also (even if inadvertently/unintentionally) changed your current working directory to match the location of the file that could not be found.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree with you, I was just seeing if it would work I wasn't sure if it would.