# FileNotFoundError: python cant find the file.txt even if it is in the same directory (MAC OS X Big Sur - PyCharmEdu IDE)

Tags: python, file, pycharm, file-not-found, macos-big-sur

**I'm on Mac OS Big Sur and I'm writing this code in PyCharmEdu IDE.**

I was just using the `open()` function in `"r"` mode in order to open a `file.txt` and read its data.

I wrote the code and created the file `input.txt` *in the same directory*;

Here is the main line where the error occurs:

```
infile = open("input.txt", "r")
```

And here is the screenshot of the directory where both files are:
[image]

The file where the code is written is `es1.py`, `input.txt` is the `txt` file obv.

However a "file not found error" occurs:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input.txt'
```

Does anyone know why this occurs?

**EDIT**: I found out that this happens since I first created the python file in the venv (virtual environment) directory as a mistake and then I refactored its path...

Anyway I don't understand why the error keeps occurring since the py file is in the correct path?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'm not so used to StackOverflow, anyway I still have the question: why does this happen even if the position of the python file has been modified?

Comment: Try adding `import os` `print(os.path.abspath(__file__))` to your code, and run it to see where python thinks the python file is.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running `infile = open("input.txt", "r")` from your console/terminal, you'll need to specify the path of the file, or put the file into the source of the terminal/console.

Another possibility is addressed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21957181/13552470) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "pwd" in your Python command line to see what directory Python is running in. If it isn't the same try changing its directory to your working folder with "cd directory_name".