# How to resolve relative import

Tags: python, pytest, python-import, python-module

Currently, I'm playing around with absolute and relative imports for my tests. Below is the example of the file structure.

File Structure:

```
project/
        main_script.py
        input1.csv
        input2.csv
        
        Testing/
                test_script.py
                test_input1.csv
                test_input2.csv
                test_output.csv
```

Code in main_script.py

```
def function1():
    {function definition here}

def function2():
    {function definition here}

def function3():
    {function definition here}
```

Code in test_script.py

```
import pytest 
from ..main_script import function1, function2, function3
```

The output I get when running test_script:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

From the examples I've read from different sources and tutorials I have watched, this should have been the solution to my problem but it's coming out with more errors. Why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Comment: No @EmmanuelMurairi. The ImportError still occurs while executing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try any one of these ways -

1. Use absolute import
2. Use standard way of import and remove **from** keyword
   Example: import main_script.function1
3. Put this inside your package's **init**.py -
   For relative imports to work in Python 3.6 -
   import os, sys; sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(**file**)))
   And now use normal import statement like :
   from main_script import function1

[Reference Attached](https://itsmycode.com/importerror-attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package/)

Do let me know if this helps out.
Happy Learning!!

Comment: The last method worked! A follow-up question to this is why can't my test script read *.csv files which is currently in the same folder as the test script. A FileNotFoundError would pop out. Is there any way to solve this? Thank you again for the solution above!!

Comment: Refer this post and let me know if it helps in solving the issue(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957131/python-not-finding-file-in-the-same-directory) OR You can use absolute path like **Users/Documents/employee1.csv** -

Comment: Using absolute path works but I would rather not let users manually change the code so instead, I went with this solution ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384358/how-to-open-my-files-in-data-folder-with-pandas-using-relative-path)). Thanks again for your help!